# MySQL Join Where Not Exists

Tags: mysql, join, not-exists

I have a MySQL query that joins two tables

- Voters
- Households

They join on `voters.household_id` and `household.id`.

Now what I need to do is to modify it where the voter table is joined to a third table called elimination, along `voter.id` and `elimination.voter_id`. However the catch is that I want to exclude any records in the voter table that have a corresponding record in the elimination table.

How do I craft a query to do this?

This is my current query:

```
SELECT `voter`.`ID`, `voter`.`Last_Name`, `voter`.`First_Name`,
       `voter`.`Middle_Name`, `voter`.`Age`, `voter`.`Sex`,
       `voter`.`Party`, `voter`.`Demo`, `voter`.`PV`,
       `household`.`Address`, `household`.`City`, `household`.`Zip`
FROM (`voter`)
JOIN `household` ON `voter`.`House_ID`=`household`.`id`
WHERE `CT` = '5'
AND `Precnum` = 'CTY3'
AND  `Last_Name`  LIKE '%Cumbee%'
AND  `First_Name`  LIKE '%John%'
ORDER BY `Last_Name` ASC
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 251, accepted):

I'd probably use a `LEFT JOIN`, which will return rows even if there's no match, and then you can select only the rows with no match by checking for `NULL`s.

So, something like:

```
SELECT V.*
FROM voter V LEFT JOIN elimination E ON V.id = E.voter_id
WHERE E.voter_id IS NULL
```

Whether that's more or less efficient than using a subquery depends on optimization, indexes, whether its possible to have more than one elimination per voter, etc.

Comment: +1 much faster on high-load then sub-queries + if U can do JOINs instead of sub-queries - just do JOINs they are much simpler for analizer.
Another useful example, U may want to get result if there are some rows in a right table or if there are no one: `SELECT V.*
FROM voter V LEFT JOIN elimination E ON V.id = E.voter_id OR E.voter_id IS NULL` ex.: if U don't want to store all records in the right table for every row from the left.

Comment: How would you modify this query to find rows that do not exist in `E`, when `E.voter_id` can be `NULL` in the dataset we're `JOIN`ing from?

Comment: You need to link the tables together with some common column or related value. But I think this could work (untested): `SELECT V.*, COUNT(E.*) AS \`countE\` FROM voter V LEFT JOIN elimination E ON V.id = E.voter_id WHERE countE = 0;`

Answer (score 11):

I'd use a 'where not exists' -- exactly as you suggest in your title:

```
SELECT `voter`.`ID`, `voter`.`Last_Name`, `voter`.`First_Name`,
       `voter`.`Middle_Name`, `voter`.`Age`, `voter`.`Sex`,
       `voter`.`Party`, `voter`.`Demo`, `voter`.`PV`,
       `household`.`Address`, `household`.`City`, `household`.`Zip`
FROM (`voter`)
JOIN `household` ON `voter`.`House_ID`=`household`.`id`
WHERE `CT` = '5'
AND `Precnum` = 'CTY3'
AND  `Last_Name`  LIKE '%Cumbee%'
AND  `First_Name`  LIKE '%John%'

AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM `elimination`
   WHERE `elimination`.`voter_id` = `voter`.`ID`
)

ORDER BY `Last_Name` ASC
LIMIT 30
```

That may be marginally faster than doing a left join (of course, depending on your indexes, cardinality of your tables, etc), and is almost certainly **much** faster than using IN.

Answer (score 9):

There are three possible ways to do that.

1. Option

   ```
   SELECT  lt.* FROM    table_left lt
   LEFT JOIN
       table_right rt
   ON      rt.value = lt.value
   WHERE   rt.value IS NULL
   ```
2. Option

   ```
   SELECT  lt.* FROM    table_left lt
   WHERE   lt.value NOT IN
   (
   SELECT  value
   FROM    table_right rt
   )
   ```
3. Option

   ```
   SELECT  lt.* FROM    table_left lt
   WHERE   NOT EXISTS
   (
   SELECT  NULL
   FROM    table_right rt
   WHERE   rt.value = lt.value
   )
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Be wary of "LEFT" JOINS - LEFT JOINS are essentially OUTER JOINS. Different RDBMS query parsers and optimizers may handle OUTER JOINS very differently. Take for instance, how LEFT (OUTER) JOINS are parsed by MySQL's query optimizer, and the difference in resulting execution plans they could evaluate to per iteration:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html

LEFT JOINS by their very nature are ALWAYS going to be NonDeterministic. IMO - they should not be used in Production code.

I prefer to write JOIN type statements in a more "old school" approach first, leaving out any specific JOIN declarations. Let the RDBMS query parser do what its designed to do - analyze your statement and translate it to most optimal execution plan based on its evaluation of your index stats and data model design. That said, the build in query parsers / optimizers can even get it wrong, trust me I've seen it happen many times. In general, I feel like taking this approach first generally provides sufficient baseline information to make informed further tuning decisions in most cases.

To illustrate - using the question query from this thread:

```sql
SELECT `voter`.`ID`, `voter`.`Last_Name`, `voter`.`First_Name`,
       `voter`.`Middle_Name`, `voter`.`Age`, `voter`.`Sex`,
       `voter`.`Party`, `voter`.`Demo`, `voter`.`PV`,
       `household`.`Address`, `household`.`City`, `household`.`Zip`
FROM (`voter`)
JOIN `household` ON `voter`.`House_ID`=`household`.`id`
WHERE `CT` = '5'
AND `Precnum` = 'CTY3'
AND  `Last_Name`  LIKE '%Cumbee%'
AND  `First_Name`  LIKE '%John%'

AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM `elimination`
   WHERE `elimination`.`voter_id` = `voter`.`ID`
)

ORDER BY `Last_Name` ASC
LIMIT 30
```

Consider it re-written without the explicit JOIN and NOT EXISTS statements above (assumes the non fully qualified fields in the WHERE clause belonged to the voter table):

```sql
SELECT v.`ID`, v.`Last_Name`, v.`First_Name`,
       v.`Middle_Name`, v.`Age`, v.`Sex`,
       v.`Party`, v.`Demo`, v.`PV`,
       h.`Address`, h.`City`, h.`Zip`
FROM `voter` v, `household` h, `elimination` e
WHERE v.`House_ID` = h.`id`
AND v.`ID` != e.`voter_id`
AND v.`CT` = '5'
AND v.`Precnum` = 'CTY3'
AND  v.`Last_Name`  LIKE '%Cumbee%'
AND  v.`First_Name`  LIKE '%John%'
ORDER BY v.`Last_Name` ASC
LIMIT 30;
```

Try writing some of your future SQL queries BOTH ways syntactically going forward, compare their results, and see what you think. Writing your SQL in the style I have suggested above comes with the added benefit of being more RDBMS agnostic, also.

Cheers!

Comment: Very long  , keep it crisp and short !

Comment: Thanks for the advice - much appreciated. For all the years I've read through countless threads searching for answers myself - I've decided its my time to start giving back. I'll make sure to keep it concise from now on.