# Get data from mysql, taking almost 436 seconds

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I am android developer and don't have much experience in mysql. I have 3 tables in mysql database.

First table :-**UserTable**

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+----------------------+
| user_id     | name      |   image    |   joining_date       |
+-------------+-------------+----------+----------------------+
|         100 | King      | defualt.jpg | 2018-05-23 20:09:27 |
|         101 | Kochhar   | defualt.jpg | 2018-05-23 20:09:27 |
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |
```

Second Table :-
**friendRequests**

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| unique_id   | from_id     |   to_id  |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
|         1  | 100          | 101      |
|         2  | 200          | 110      |
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
```

Third Table :-
**friends**

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| unique_id   | from_id     |   to_id  |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
|         1  | 104          | 101      |
|         2  | 206          | 110      |
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
```

I want to get the list of users who are not friends to me and also we have not pending friend request. So i tried with following query:-

```
SELECT usertable.name,
       usertable.user_id,
       usertable.image
FROM   `UserTable` AS usertable
WHERE  usertable.user_id <> '100'
       AND (SELECT Count(*)
            FROM   friendrequests
            WHERE  ( to_id = '100'
                     AND from_id = usertable.user_id )
                    OR ( to_id = usertable.user_id
                         AND from_id = '100' )) = 0
       AND (SELECT Count(*)
            FROM   friends
            WHERE  to_id = usertable.user_id
                   AND from_id = '100'
                    OR to_id = '100'
                       AND from_id = usertable.user_id) = 0
ORDER  BY usertable.joining_date DESC
LIMIT  10
```

It is working but takes 436 seconds. What is the proper way to write this query?

Comment: `user` is a Keyword. It is not a good candidate for table name. You should really name your table to something else.

Comment: Thank You @MadhurBhaiya. I have updated my question.

Comment: Avoid to use select in your select and try to use some join maybe?

Comment: Can you five us a SQL fiddle please with your data to test some request?

Comment: Smells like you don't have any indexes.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some other way to do it :

**1) Using `NOT IN`**

You add a condition on `usertable.user_id` that should'nt be in a list of id : those id are all the id of the table `friendrequests` and `friends` that have `to_id` or `from_id` = 100.

```
SELECT 
  usertable.name,
  usertable.user_id,
  usertable.image
FROM `UserTable` AS usertable
WHERE usertable.user_id <> '100'
  AND usertable.user_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT from_id as user_id FROM friendrequests WHERE to_id = '100'
     UNION
     SELECT to_id as user_id FROM friendrequests WHERE from_id = '100'
     UNION
     SELECT from_id as user_id FROM friends WHERE to_id = '100'
     UNION
     SELECT to_id as user_id FROM friends WHERE from_id = '100')               
ORDER  BY usertable.joining_date DESC
LIMIT  10
```

**EDIT** according to Rick James comment, same with no union:

```
SELECT 
  usertable.name,
  usertable.user_id,
  usertable.image
FROM `UserTable` AS usertable
WHERE usertable.user_id <> '100'
  AND usertable.user_id NOT IN (SELECT from_id as user_id FROM friendrequests WHERE to_id = '100')
  AND usertable.user_id NOT IN (SELECT to_id as user_id FROM friendrequests WHERE from_id = '100')
  AND usertable.user_id NOT IN (SELECT from_id as user_id FROM friends WHERE to_id = '100')
  AND usertable.user_id NOT IN (SELECT to_id as user_id FROM friends WHERE from_id = '100')               
ORDER  BY usertable.joining_date DESC
LIMIT  10
```

**2) Using a `LEFT JOIN`**

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750343/mysql-join-where-not-exists) and tried to use the same logic : you make some `LEFT JOIN` with the other table and add a condition where those join return NULL value

```
SELECT 
  usertable.name,
  usertable.user_id,
  usertable.image
FROM `UserTable` AS usertable
LEFT JOIN friendrequests as FRa on FRa.from_id = usertable_user_id
LEFT JOIN friendrequests as FRb on FRb.to_id   = usertable_user_id
LEFT JOIN friends        as Fa  on Fa.from_id  = usertable_user_id
LEFT JOIN friends        as Fb  on Fb.to_id    = usertable_user_id
WHERE usertable.user_id <> '100' 
  AND FRa.from_id IS NULL
  AND FRb.to_id IS NULL
  AND Fa.from_id IS NULL
  AND Fb.to_id IS NULL
```

**3) Using `NOT EXISTS`**

```
SELECT 
  usertable.name,
  usertable.user_id,
  usertable.image
FROM `UserTable` AS usertable
WHERE usertable.user_id <> '100'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT from_id as user_id FROM friendrequests WHERE to_id = '100')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT to_id as user_id FROM friendrequests WHERE from_id = '100')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT from_id as user_id FROM friends WHERE to_id = '100')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT to_id as user_id FROM friends WHERE from_id = '100')               
ORDER  BY usertable.joining_date DESC
LIMIT  10
```

Sorry but with no sample data or SQL Fiddle to test those query I can't tell you if it return what you want or if it's really faster...

---

**EDIT** : This page is from 2009 so the result have change since ! I won't erase it since you still have the query structure I used before :

I recommand you to looks this page to understand the difference between those queries and give you some idea to achieve what you want : https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

A third way is proposed in this page (using `NOT EXISTS`) but according to the test it's not efficient :

> This query, however, is a little bit less efficient than the previous two: it takes 0.92 s.
>
> This is not much of a performance drop, however, the query takes 27% more time.

Comment: A lot of effort has gone into the Optimizer since 2009, especially in the areas being discussed here.  Don't trust that link.

Comment: Try to avoid `UNION`; it has some overhead and avoids some optimization paths.  Try the `NOT IN` solution with fpir `AND .. NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` clauses.  And do the equivalent with `NOT EXISTS`:  four `AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ... )` clauses.

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps gourav is running an old version?  You have a timing--are you speaking for him?  Or did you run an independent test?

Comment: I just tried to give him some other way to achieve what he wanted, I don't know how looks his database (index or other thing) so hard to make a test